# StopIteration shows in run files but not in command prompt

Tags: python

I am new in Python
I write this code in command prompt, and it works fine. But when I write it in a .py file and run it, it shows StopIteration error.

```
import os
x = next(os.walk('E:/pycode/images'))[1]
for y in x:
    z = next(os.walk(y))[2]
    print(z)
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Where is the exception happening (which `next` call is it)? Is there an empty folder within `E:/pycode/images`?

Comment: It's in this `z = next(os.walk(y))[2]` . No, all the folders are not empty

Comment: Well, you might want to try putting some troubleshooting code in then to see why you're getting an exception. Put a `try` and `except` statement around the location of the exception and print out `y` when it occurs.

Comment: I'm suprised to see `next` in beginner's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call `os.walk` multiple times, it already runs recursively. If you want to print the file names that exist exactly one-folder deep, use this:

```
import os

w = os.walk('E:/pycode/images')
next(w) # ignore files in top level folder
for path, dirs, files in w:
    dirs.clear() # don't go any deeper along this path
    for f in files:
        print(f) # optional: print(os.path.join(path, f))
```

Your existing code was probably raising an exception because one of the folders you were calling `os.walk` on was empty. If you call `next` on an empty iterator, it raises `StopIteration`. I have no idea why that was only happening some of the time though (unless the contents of the folder changed in between runs).

Comment: Actually I need both the folder names and the file names inside the respective folder.

Comment: Then you can do something with `dirs` before you call its `clear()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid stopiteration error using try-catch given below

```
import os

x = next(os.walk('E:/pycode/images'))[1]
for y in x:
  try:
    z = next(os.walk(y))[2]
    print(z)
  except:
    break
```

Comment: You could greatly improve your answer by giving a little context and explanation in form of written English sentences. Just code doesn't help in understanding.